# How do I enable Remote Desktop connection on Xubuntu 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, xubuntu, remote-desktop

How do I enable Remote Desktop connection on Xubuntu 11.10? I do not find any options such as those present in Ubuntu?

Comment: Are you (just) trying to setup remote desktop, or do you need auto-start - to allow connection without local login?  See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/83824/how-can-i-start-a-vnc-server-before-login

Comment: restart you system if its unable to execute the command sudo apt-get install xrdp and again run the same.

Answer (score 21):

1. Input the following line to install vino:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install vino
   ```
2. Input the following line to configure vino:

   ```
   vino-preferences
   ```

Follow the onscreen instructions to make changes to your remote desktop sharing preferences.

1. Go to XFCE settings manager and select "session and startup" and "application auto start"
2. Click Add and Enter the following command to start the vino server:

   ```
   /usr/lib/vino/vino-server
   ```

Comment: for xubuntu 16.04-18.10 use next instruction https://medium.com/@aldo_mx/simplest-way-to-configure-vnc-server-in-xubuntu-16-04-lts-and-newer-6c0b3ae21fe5

Answer (score 16):

Install the xrdp server ( Remote Desktop Protocol Server).
It allows to connect to your ubuntu box from any rdp client.

What the other answer describe is called "desktop sharing" and is not the same thing as "remote desktop"  . See the accepted answer for [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56145/cant-connect-to-remote-desktop) for more explanation :

> "Remote Desktop" in Ubuntu is not the same thing as in Windows. 
>    It's intended to share your running desktop with someone else. 
>    In 11.10, it's been renamed to "Desktop Sharing" to better reflect that.

Answer (score 13):

try `sudo apt-get install xrdp`. This allows you to connect to the Ubuntu from RDP software or remote desktop of windows.

Comment: does not work in my ubuntu 14

Answer (score 8):

On Ubuntu 16.04 :

```
apt-get install xrdp xfce4
echo xfce4-session >~/.xsession
/etc/init.d/xrdp restart
```

You could connect after from Windows or Linux.

Comment: Still works on Raspberry Pi running Ubuntu 20.04, thanks!

Comment: In Xubuntu 18.04, `apt-get install xrdp` and a reboot was enough.

Answer (score 3):

Using remote desktop on Ubuntu is really easy. You just go into system settings and enable it and it will do all the work for you. .  besides a few boxes to check. This is a pretty easy tutorial if you want to try it. worked for me. [Remote Desktop Ubuntu 11.10 Set Up Instructions](http://www.ubuntulinuxguide.com/remote-desktop-xubuntu-12-04)

Comment: link is dead. more helpful would be to list what app you open to change such settings, and what settings you must change.

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20121115163800/http://www.ubuntulinuxguide.com/remote-desktop-xubuntu-12-04 shows it was the standard apt-get install, and then vino-preferences. Those two steps are already in https://askubuntu.com/a/71357. Unfortunately, the screencaps don't seem to have made it into (at least that capture on) the WayBack Machine—but unless they show something different than the article text, it's just the usual way of installing things on Ubuntu, which this answer seems to say is unnecessary.