# Share Ubuntu server desktop remotly

Tags: server, remote

Is it possible to setup a Ubuntu server desktop environment with a user and share this environment (both remote control and ftp of some sort) with multiple computers (especially Microsoft Windows 7/8).

For example a project group where everyone in the group can interact with the environment from their own computer somewhere else in the world and show the others the presentation, a file or a image. Code together or play games.

**If something like this already exist I'd love a redirect to a guide.**

Comment: Are you looking for a shared remote desktop or do you want separate desktops for every session ?

Comment: I'm looking for a shared remote desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Server**

If you want to have one desktop to share between all users try vino.

To install:

```
sudo apt-get install vino
```

To configure the vino software use:

```
vino-preferences
```

Inside `vino-preferences` you enable

- Sharing -> Allow users to view your desktop
- Allow other users to control your desktop

You should also enable some sort of security, for example the:

- Require the user to enter this password *****

You might also want to see: [How do I enable Remote Desktop connection on Xubuntu 11.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/71309/how-do-i-enable-remote-desktop-connection-on-xubuntu-11-10)

**Ubuntu Client**

On the client machine you also need software to connect to your vino vnc server. Remmina desktop is a good choice as it also gives you the possibility to create ssh tunnels automatically.

To install:

```
 sudo apt-get install remmina
```

To start: Press <kbd>WIN</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> and select 'Remmina Remote Desktop Client'

Inside Remmina click the pluss icon to create a new connection.
Once opened, eneter your server name and credentials (if you chose password , leav the username empty). Select Color depth : High color (16 bit) and Quality : Good.

Click Connect.

(These options are the ones that have worked OK for me - you might want to experiment with them)

If you need to create a SSH tunnel as well - open the SSH tab.

**Windows Client**

To connect to your vino server from windows - you have a lot of options.
Try for example real VNC:

http://www.realvnc.com/download/viewer/

Good luck :)

Comment: Thank you! I'll get to it later and report back in the weekend.