# How to use my Windows 7 laptop as a remote desktop for my xubuntu 16.04

Tags: xubuntu, remote-desktop, xrdp

I am new to Linux, have only had it for a month now. I installed XRDP on Xubuntu 16.04 and made sure to type in sudo service xrdp start. After doing so, I opened remote desktop on my windows 7 laptop and typed in the IP address for the Xubuntu desktop I have. The windows remote desktop keeps giving me an error of, that remote desktop can't connect to the remote computer for one of these reasons:

1. remote access to the server is not enabled.
2. the remote computer is turned off.
3. the remote computer is not available on the network.

XRDP is on, the computer is on, and it is on the network. Am I doing something wrong? How do I connect to my Xubuntu desktop from my windows 7 laptop using RDP?

Answer (score 1):

Try this (borrowed from [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/928461/258059)) -

On Ubuntu 16.04:

```
apt-get install xrdp xfce4
echo xfce4-session >~/.xsession
/etc/init.d/xrdp restart
```

Then you should be able to connect from Windows or Linux.